# Why is DataFrameGroupBy.apply called n+1 times when there are only n groups?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my data:

```
+--------+----------------+
| class  |     title      |
+--------+----------------+
| ClassA | ClassA Title 1 |
| ClassA | ClassA Title 2 |
| ClassA | ClassA Title 3 |
| ClassB | ClassB Title 1 |
| ClassB | ClassB Title 2 |
| ClassB | ClassB Title 3 |
| ClassC | ClassC Title 1 |
| ClassC | ClassC Title 2 |
| ClassC | ClassC Title 3 |
+--------+----------------+
```

When grouped on the `class` column there are only 3 groups, but when I run the following code it prints 4 groups -- the first group is being repeated:

```
df.groupby(["class"]).apply(lambda group: print(group))
```

This prints:

```
    class           title
0  ClassA  ClassA Title 1
1  ClassA  ClassA Title 2
2  ClassA  ClassA Title 3
    class           title
0  ClassA  ClassA Title 1
1  ClassA  ClassA Title 2
2  ClassA  ClassA Title 3
    class           title
3  ClassB  ClassB Title 1
4  ClassB  ClassB Title 2
5  ClassB  ClassB Title 3
    class           title
6  ClassC  ClassC Title 1
7  ClassC  ClassC Title 2
8  ClassC  ClassC Title 3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

**Notes**

In the current implementation apply calls func twice on the first column/row to decide whether it can take a fast or slow code path. This can lead to unexpected behavior if func has side-effects, as they will take effect twice for the first column/row.